# Copy constructor undefined

Tags: equals, tostring, copy-constructor

So I was doing my assignment to create a copy constructor.
However, the program keeps giving an error about The constructor Shoes (string, double) is undefined. What does this mean and How I can fix this to get copy constructor?

```
public class Shoes {


    //Instance Variables
    private String brand; // The shoes brand
    private String color; // The shoes color
    private double size;  // The shoes size


    // Assigns instance variables to default values
        public Shoes(){
            brand = "";
            color = "";
            size = 0;
        }

    //Constructor
    public Shoes (String brand, String color, double size)
    {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.color = color;
        this.size = size;
    }


    /**
     * The setBrand method stores a value in the brand field.
     * @param brand The value to store in Brand.
     */

    public void setBrand (String brand)
    {
        this.brand=brand;
    }

    /**
     * The setColor method stores a value in the color field.
     * @param color the value to store in color
     */

    public void setColor (String color)
    {
        this.color=color;
    }

    /**
     * The setSize method stores a value in the size field.
     * @param size the value to store in size
     */

    public void setSize (double size)
    {
        this.size=size;
    }

    /**
     * The getBrand method returns Shoes brand.
     * @return the value in the brand field
     */

    public String getBrand()
    {
        return brand;
    }

    /**
     * the getColor method returns Shoes color.
     * @return the value in the color field
     */

    public String getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    /**
     * the getSize method returns Shoes size
     * @return the value in the size field
     */

    public double getSize()
    {
        return size;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String str = " My shoes  " + brand + color + size; 
        return str;
    }
    public boolean equal(Shoes object2)
    {
        boolean status;
        if (brand.equals(object2.brand) &&
                size == object2.size)
                 status = true;  // Yes, the objects are equal.
              else
                 status = false; // No, the objects are not equal.

              // Return the value in status.
              return status;
    }
    public Shoes copy()
    {
        Shoes copyObject = new Shoes(brand,size);

    }
    // prints out the values of all instance variables of your object
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(brand);
        System.out.println(color);
        System.out.println(size);

    }


}
```

and this is another class that helps this program to run successfully.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a object
        Shoes shoes = new Shoes();

        //Call  the object's setBrand method, passing Nike as a argument.
        shoes.setBrand("Nike");

        //Call  the object's setColor method, passing Pink as a argument.
        shoes.setColor("Pink");

        //Call  the object's setSize method, passing 7 as a argument.
        shoes.setSize(7);

        shoes.display();

          // Create a Stock object.
          Shoes company1 = new Shoes("Nike",7.00);

          // Declare a Stock variable
          Shoes company2;

          // Make company2 reference a copy of the object
          // referenced by company1.
          company2 = company1.copy();

          // Display the contents of both objects.
          System.out.println("Company 1:\n" + company1);
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("Company 2:\n" + company2);

          // Confirm that we actually have two objects.
          if (company1 == company2)
          {
             System.out.println("The company1 and company2 " +
                      "variables reference the same object.");
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("The company1 and company2 " +
                    "variables reference different objects.");
    }

}
```

The both program has same problem which the constructor (string,double) is undefined. What should I do with this error? I really need a help.

Comment: It means that you haven't created such a constructor, which is true.

Comment: BTW copy constructors mean `public Shoes(Shoes other)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you need to add a constructor with this parameters:

```
   //Constructor
    public Shoes (String brand, double size)
    {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.size = size;
    }
```

Comment: wow.. I just spent 1 day to figure out how I did wrong but.. Thank you so much.